# How do I disable Tumblr Photosets or change the size of them? (there is no block:photoset in my html)

Tags: html, set, photo, tumblr, image-resizing

I have been searching for weeks for a resolution to my problem.
I know very little about editing html and I have tried the solutions posted on this site but none of them seems to work.

I am using [the "Just Plain" theme](http://www.tumblr.com/theme/106) and that is a theme that was created before the new photoset layout. I don't think it has been updated, because I cannot find `{block:Photos}` `{/block:Photos}` anywhere within the themes html.

I have edited the html to make the post size `750px` but I'm afraid that's about as far as my skills with html go. I'm a complete novice.

If anyone could help me disable the photoset function or resize the images in a photoset to `750px` and have them appear one after each other then I would be very grateful.

I would post the block of html that needs editing but like I said, there is no block whatsoever regarding photosets.

Sorry if this doesn't make sense.

The tumblr in question is http://nothingbutthe-truth.com

Comment: Tumblr link is NSFW (not safe for work), contains nudity. Please notify others in the future

Answer (score 2):

this is how I did it:

```
{block:Photoset}
{block:Photos} 
<figure class="post-image">
    <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
</figure>
{/block:Photos} 
{block:Caption}
<div class="post-description">
    {Caption}
</div>
{/block:Caption}
{/block:Photoset}
```

Everything inside the {block:Photos} tag will be rendered for each photo in the set.
So you can define your own markup instead of relying on the provided iframe.

Inside these tags you can work with the standard block-variables of the photo posts.
http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photo-posts

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable photosets entirely, just delete {block:Photoset} and everything in between.

In terms of resizing, you can actually change the size of the images used by selection by using {Photoset-700} like so:

```
            {block:Photoset}
                <li class="post photoset">
                    {Photoset-700}

                    {block:Caption}
                        <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                    {/block:Caption}
                </li>
            {/block:Photoset}
```

This isn't 750px exactly, but 700px should be close enough. I don't think it's possible to get any higher resolution images anyway so it's the closest you can get to exact resolution.

You can learn more about creating themes here: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photoset-posts